# CONTROL+C does not work for python web server in mac

Tags: python, django

I start the Django web-server using 'python manage.py runserver 8070', but unable to quit the server using CONTROL-C in my mac. CONTROL-C copy's the content though. Please advise on which key-board shortcut should I use to quit the web-server.

```
$ python manage.py runserver 8070
Validating models...
0 errors found
November 22, 2014 - 12:11:27
Django version 1.5.4, using settings 'tango_with_django_project.settings'
Development server is running at http:// 127.0.0.1:8070/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Starting the process in the background using "python manage.py runserver 8070&" and then killing it using "kill -9 " works, but i would like to know the actual key-board shortcut to quit the process.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `COMMAND-C`?  On a mac this should send SIGINT (if control+c doesn't already), which is what `CONTROL-C` sends on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sometimes CONTROL-C works and not at times, hence wondering if there is any other alternative to exit the process without a kill command.

Thanks in advance.